# Upload multiple videos from my app

Tags: android, video, upload, photo

how to Upload multiple video from android phone.  i am doing one project uploading 10 photos and 5 videos.i  uploaded one video using multipart request but i am not having idea to upload 5 video(Multiple) from android app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the same approach you used for one, again for the other videos.

The upload itself will almost certainly support parallel asynchronous uploads so can upload them at the same time or serially, one after the other.

If the upload time does not matter to you then you can probably choose whichever is easiest - if it does and you want, for example, a shorter one to be ready as soon as possible then you could experiment with either uploading them in parallel or sorting them in your app first and uploading the shorter ones first.

Note that at some stage you may reach a limit on parallel connections but if you are using any of the popular HTTP libraries like Volley, retrofit etc they should handle edge conditions like this gracefully.